# Pagination for single div tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-pagination

Want to create pagination for single div tag,(i.e) if text length exceed div tag then it should act as page 2 and etc,, how it can be done can u able to share the ideas?

Comment: Is pagination really what you want in that situation? I think users are happier to scroll to see extra content than to have to load a new page. (And if the `DIV` has a fixed height you can always give it `overflow: auto` to give it scrollbars)

Comment: @Gareth actually i want to split the text inside div tag when it exceed that height

Answer (score 0):

Well obviously somewhere in your code you set (or change) the content and there before setting the content you should check the new length.

```
var loadedData= new Array();

$.get('page.html', function(data){

loadedData= data.split('\n');
// or for example each data is in a paragraph:
$(data).find("p").each(function(index){
loadedData[i]=$(this).html()
});

});
```

Comment: can you able to give solution briefly

Comment: can you tell me how you change the div content? I mean do you get the new content using ajax? or they are set in server-side when page is rendering? and ...

Comment: m using single div tag only.. in that i m loading one htm page, while it loading it should be splitted, according to the height of div tag. where we can use an array for to store the splitting content.

Comment: sorry for late response my internet got a problem. and I was dc for a while.